# Getting GET http://example.co.in/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cpanel, video-player

I have uploaded the React js folder to cPanel and now when I open the domain, its showing blank and showing the error message in console as:

**GET http://demo.example.co.in/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

Below is my index.html file:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Luit – Watch &amp; Download Movies, Web Series, Music Video, Short Movies and much more</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themify-icons.css">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js@7/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- City -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/themes@1/dist/city/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video-player.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/verifyotp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/terms.css" >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">



  </head>
  <body>

    <script  type="text/babel" src="/__/firebase/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script  type="text/babel" src="/__/firebase/8.4.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Firebase -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/country.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/video-player.js"></script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I also got an error in the video-player.js as :
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at video-player.js:121**

Can anyone please help me with this?

here is the video-player.js file

```
        var player = document.querySelector('.player');
        var video = document.querySelector('#video');
        var playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
        var volumeBtn = document.querySelector('.volume-btn');
        var volumeSlider = document.querySelector('.volume-slider');
        var volumeFill = document.querySelector('.volume-filled');
        var progressSlider = document.querySelector('.progress');
        var progressFill = document.querySelector('.progress-filled');
        var textCurrent = document.querySelector('.time-current');
        var textTotal = document.querySelector('.time-total');
        var speedBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.speed-item');
        var fullscreenBtn =document.querySelector('.fullscreen'); 

        //GLOBAL VARS
        let lastVolume = 1;
        let isMouseDown = false;

        //PLAYER FUNCTIONS
        function togglePlay() {
            if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();  
            }
            playBtn.classList.toggle('paused');
        }
        function togglePlayBtn() {
            playBtn.classList.toggle('playing');
        }

        function toggleMute() {
            if(video.volume) {
                lastVolume = video.volume;
                video.volume = 0;
                volumeBtn.classList.add('muted');
                volumeFill.style.width = 0;
            } else {
                video.volume = lastVolume;
                volumeBtn.classList.remove('muted');
                volumeFill.style.width = `${lastVolume*100}%`;
            }
        }
        function changeVolume(e) {
                volumeBtn.classList.remove('muted');
                let volume = e.offsetX/volumeSlider.offsetWidth;
                volume<0.1 ? volume = 0 : volume=volume; 
                volumeFill.style.width = `${volume*100}%`;
                video.volume = volume;
                if (volume > 0.7) {
                    volumeBtn.classList.add('loud');
                } else if (volume < 0.7 && volume > 0) {
                    volumeBtn.classList.remove('loud');
                } else if (volume == 0) {
                    volumeBtn.classList.add('muted');
                }
                lastVolume = volume;
        }
        function neatTime(time) {
          // var hours = Math.floor((time % 86400)/3600)
          var minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600)/60);
          var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
            seconds = seconds>9?seconds:`0${seconds}`;
            return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        }
        function updateProgress(e) {
            progressFill.style.width = `${video.currentTime/video.duration*100}%`;
            textCurrent.innerHTML = `${neatTime(video.currentTime)} / ${neatTime(video.duration)}`;
            // textTotal.innerHTML = neatTime(video.duration);
            // console.log(progressFill.style.width);
        }
        function setProgress(e) {
            const newTime = e.offsetX/progressSlider.offsetWidth;
            progressFill.style.width = `${newTime*100}%`;
            video.currentTime = newTime*video.duration;
        }
        function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
          if(element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
          } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
        }
        function exitFullscreen() {
          if(document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
          } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
          }
        }
        var fullscreen = false;
        function toggleFullscreen() {
            fullscreen? exitFullscreen() : launchIntoFullscreen(player)
            fullscreen = !fullscreen;
        }
        function setSpeed(e) {
            console.log(parseFloat(this.dataset.speed));
            video.playbackRate = this.dataset.speed;
            speedBtns.forEach(speedBtn =>   speedBtn.classList.remove('active'));
            this.classList.add('active');
        }
        function handleKeypress(e) {
            switch (e.key) {
                case " ":
                    togglePlay();
                case "ArrowRight":
                    video.currentTime += 5;
                case "ArrowLeft":
                    video.currentTime -= 5;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
        //EVENT LISTENERS
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
        video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
        video.addEventListener('play', togglePlayBtn);
        video.addEventListener('pause', togglePlayBtn);
        video.addEventListener('ended', togglePlayBtn);
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress);
        video.addEventListener('canplay', updateProgress);
        volumeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMute);
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', () => isMouseDown = true)
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isMouseDown = false)
        // volumeSlider.addEventListener('mouseover', changeVolume);
        volumeSlider.addEventListener('click', changeVolume);
        progressSlider.addEventListener('click', setProgress);
        fullscreenBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFullscreen);
        speedBtns.forEach(speedBtn => {
            speedBtn.addEventListener('click', setSpeed);
        })
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeypress);
```

Comment: For the js error can you show the `video-player.js` file contents?

Comment: I have added the file.